# Two dimensional array - update certain poistion

Tags: java

I have a two dimensional array and also have the start and end point. The array is initialized to zero and i have to update from the start to end position with one. What is the best algorithm to do it ?

For example if start and end position are (2,2) and (4,2) i need to start updating the values from 2,2 and end at 4,2. Rest of the array should be zero.

Comment: Why not use a nested for-loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just loop over the array from start index to end index.

```
for(int i = startCol; i <= endCol; i++) {
   for(int j = startRow; j <= endRow; j++) {
       a[i][j] = 1;
   }
}
```

it's going to take `O(n^2)` time but I think that's the best you can do.

Comment: well he asked for the best algorithm so I felt it was relevant to mention how good my algorithm was.

Comment: Actually I think your solution is much better than O(n^2) - (n is normally considered the search space) its just linearly updating the items that actually need to be updated. If only one item needed updating, for instance startCol=5, endcol=5, startRow=10, endRow=10, you would only do one iteration, even if the array had 1 million entries. So its the most efficient you can ever get.

Comment: @jbx it's still O(n^2) because big-O is the worse case scenario and in the worse case you have to update the entire matrix. I guess you could consider it O(n*m) if the matrix is not square however.

Comment: @twain249 Then the worst case is O(n) since you have n items, irrespective of whether they're square, rectangle, a list or a tree. O(n) just measures complexity with respect to the size of the search space. Is it increasing exponentially with the number of items? No its linear. n^2 means that with just one extra item the complexity will increase exponentially. For instance if an array has 100 items, an O(n) algorithm will take 100 iterations and if you add 1 extra item it will take 101. An O(n^2) algorithm will take 10000 iterations and 1 extra item will take it up to 10201, a big difference!

Comment: @jdx Every time I've ever seen an algorithm with respect to multi-dimensional array the array's capacity is always been referred to as either `n-by-n` or `n-by-m`. That's what I based my O(n^2).